# Does GDAX use its own wallet to send Bitcoin on my behalf?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, coinbase-transaction, gdax

I am new to cryptocurrencies and Bitcoin specifically. I recently made a transaction by transferring some Bitcoin from my GDAX wallet to my Binance wallet.

Here is my public key: https://blockchain.info/address/1CQUN1tN1BrD8dPtqFjUeKRGcdYmEhdafh

Why is the sender of the Bitcoin from an address that does not belong to me? I checked my GDAX public key which changes every time I refresh the page.

If you click on the the public key that sent the Bitcoin, it shows that it has made another transaction for 0.98504441 BTC to a different address.

So I have a few questions:

1. Why does my Bitcoin public address change everytime I refresh the page on GDAX?
2. Why does the sender of my Bitcoin also have another transaction to a different public key?
3. Does GDAX send out Bitcoin from a shared wallet on my behalf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answers to your questions:**

**1.** [GDAX generate a new address for every transaction, they consider a generated address as used. The reason for a new address is to protect your privacy, so a third-party can not view all other transactions associated with your account by looking up an address you have used before](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/2276500).

**2. and 3.** [When a GDAX user sends digital currency from their wallet, the address it comes "from" is one of GDAX's many hot wallet addresses. Any coins sent back to that address would be sent to GDAX, not your own wallet](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2371899-how-do-i-refund-a-digital-currency-transaction-). So yes, kind of like shared wallet.